# The Ubuntu 20.04 operating system installed on external hard disks often crashes

Tags: dual-boot, 20.04, partitioning, nvidia, external-hdd

[crash information](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DexDt.jpg)

I've installed Ubuntu20.04 on a mypassport external hard disk last year, I divided it into five partitions:

```
/dev/sda1:UEFI
/dev/sda2:swap (20G)
/dev/sda3:/
/dev/sda4:/home
/dev/sda5:/usr
```

recently I resized partition using gparted on live CD.
afterwards, the OS often crashed even though I checked file system many times without issues.

```
sudo disk -l
sudo fsck -f /dev/sda*
```

laptop information:

```
RAM:                7.7G
CPU:                Intel® Core™ i7-9750H CPU @ 2.60GHz × 12 
Graphics card:      NVIDIA Corporation TU117M [GeForce GTX 1650 Mobile 
OS:                 Ubuntu 20.04.5 LTS X86_64
Core:               5.15.85/5.15.0-67-generic
External-hdd size:  500G
Orininal OS:        Windows 10
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The obvious problem seems to be that gparted failed to do it's job properly;
to repair it, the main requirement is:
in depth knowledge of the file system(s) involved, or using software that has that built in, e.g. [TestDisk](https://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk) -----> *but that might also fail, which is why my main advice is to do the following...*

The easy (least effort) way out is:
Save as much personal data as possible and then reinstall.
*And this is due to the fact that any fix-in place operation (e.g. Testdisk above) may leave incomplete, corrupted or missing data - as future things to stumble on.*

Partitions:
Generally, *if you do not have specific needs,*
my advice is to move only /home **onto a separate DISK**
This is due to practical reasons; simpler handling in case of OS upgrades and other changes.

I also advice against reuse of content in `~/.config`, `~/.local` and such, there may well be subtle differences which has potential to cause trouble if used. Save them only for reference, pick only portions that you verify to be the same as in the earlier use - one setting at a time.

Comment: thanks for your help, I'll consider your suggestion. But reinstall takes too much effort, Is there any other way to fix it?

Comment: As is stated above, TestDisk might be it, it is the main Linux "regain data" application.

Comment: Sorry that I didn't see it, I'll give it a try and mark your answer accepted